# Classic Sites will be deprecated over the holidays?

Tags: online, classic, modern

I had a ticket open with Microsoft where they mentioned (casually) that Classic sites will be deprecated within a few weeks. This is a big deal for us as an Enterprise! We have custom branding and code everywhere throughout our tenant.

Not to mention there are a plethora of things in Modern that don't work or are not available. I assume they'll just hack it together and load everything in an iFrame.

Has anybody heard any official news or knows of a communication that will go out describing what to expect over Christmas when MS deprecates Classic?

Comment: When you say classic sites you mean the option to chose not to use modern experience?

Comment: No haven't heard such a thing. By "deprecated" , I think it would mean that classic sites will stop getting updates and new features. Existing solutions will work as is. However, modern sites will be the ones getting upgrades.

Comment: yes, I hope you're right @Gautam. I was confused by the statement that was given to me that's why I wanted to ask for clarification from the community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official statement by Microsoft is

> [We're not deprecating the "classic" experience; both "classic" and "modern" will coexist.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/modern-experience-customizations)

Though as Gautam mentioned, all new feature for SharePoint will mostly be targeted towards Modern UI and both UI types will coexist for quite sometime. Still would recommend to start looking into moving customization from classic to modern UI, for whatever you can and not wait for feature parity between classic and modern UI. As this will require you to analyse changes at all levels (System, Process, Organizational & Mindset), so earlier the better.

Comment: Thank you sir. A side note buried in an article is official? ugh