# Sharepoint online- Classic UI Support

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, classic

what would be the maximum time limit microsoft has suggested to change from classic UI to Modern UI?

Comment: DIdnt get your question . If you are thinking of moving from classic sites to modern sites here's the standard blog from Microsoft that may help you.    https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/transform/modernize-classic-sites

Answer (score 1):

Current advise from MS is that they will be supported, so for now you don't need to change. Enterprises have invested a lot in the classic experience site so MS needs to take that into account.

> "We're not deprecating the "classic" experience; both "classic" and
>   "modern" will coexist."

REF: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/modern-experience-customizations

I think the problem will be that they will be supported but no new features will be developed for it as Modern and Teams get all the attention.

There are as well those threads which may give you more insight:
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint-Developer/Classic-mode-support-timeline/td-p/3640

[Classic Sites will be deprecated over the holidays?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/231445/classic-sites-will-be-deprecated-over-the-holidays)

There as well those discussions: